# TeamCity use subdomain on Windows Machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, tomcat, teamcity

I have a TeamCity Install running on a Windows Machine which works on `http://localhost:9999` I want to make my TeamCity web server available to external developers for a specific host entry.  i.e. `http://teamcity.mydomain.com/` how do I do this?

I have never worked with Tomcat before, so the more details the better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TeamCity server is Internet facing all you need to do is make sure that you have a DNS entry for `teamcity.mydomain.com` that resolves to the public IP address of your server.

If your TeamCity server is behind a gateway device (firewall, router, etc) you'll still need to create the aforementioned DNS entry, but you'll want it to resolve to the public IP of your gateway device.  Then you set up a rule on your gateway to forward requests to your TeamCity server.

**EDIT:**
Another thought would be to set up a reverse proxy that you could use to rewrite the URL to add the port.

Comment: actually this only gets me halfway.  How do I route teamcity.mydomain.com to Tomcat on port 9999?  Can I do this without creating a DNS entry on my DNS server?

Comment: @Adam Ah, I see.  Well, if your server is internet facing the you don't.  You need to include the port number in the URL for your external devs.  If your server is internal then it might be possible to to a port redirect on your gateway device but that depends on what your device supports.  They don't all support port redirections.  A DNS entry is required in any situation.  Without it your external devs won't be able to resolve `teamcity.mydomain.com`

Comment: @Adam I just added an edit with another thought about how you might be able to do the port redirect.

Comment: Since its a windows box I just created a HTTP Redirect from my subdomain.domain.com to domain.com:9999.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adam Excellent, thanks for the follow-up.  That's essentially the same thing.  IIS is acting as a reverse proxy.